# Logic App and Stored Procedure for large xml data

Tags: sql-server, xml, large-data, large-files, azure-logic-apps

I was trying to solve a smaller integration through logic apps in Azure.

I have a Stored Procedure that selects data from a database and outputs XML as result.

The thing is that the Xml result is about 50k rows and pretty large.
I made an on-premises gateway connection to run the Stored Procedure through logic apps. but when I get the result, not only does it split the big xml, but it also cuts the whole result after about 15k rows.

I know I could use blobs, which means I need to export the sql-xml to files first, which also means that I need to use BCP with something like powershell to export the xml to file in best way. But, I'm trying to scipt most of the on premises steps. I want this solution to be a cloud-based one as much as possible.

Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So...

I have boiled it down to two possible outcomes to why this problem occurs.

first one is that I noised I got this error when trying to open the xml im sql server.

> '~vs8D51.xml' is too large to open with XML editor. The maximum file size is '10' MB. Please update the registry key 'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\13.0_Config\XmlEditor\MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService' to change the maximum size.

Which makes me think that the stored procedure in Azure Logic apps doesn't fetch  a result larger than 10mb because of the restrain in sql server.

I have tried to change it in regedit, but every time I restart sql server manager it resets to 10mb.

I have no idea if this is a correct assessment of the problem but its a thought...

Second, a colleague told me he had a similar problem with an file from an FTP.
He said that in some weird way the logic app doesn't get all the data because of some kind of timeout that happens in the background...

He had to fetch the file content in split pieces and somehow stream it through the workflow of the logic app and then recreate the whole thing and save it to a file on the other end of the integration.

That made me think of trying out this: [SQL Pagination for bulk data transfer with Logic Apps](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/40060.sql-pagination-for-bulk-data-transfer-with-logic-apps.aspx?Sort=MostRecent&PageIndex=1)

It works, but not quite how i want it to work. I can stream the data and save them to blob, but that is as results from the table itself, not as split pieces of the whole XML of that same data...

Anyone know of a way to maybe iterate/paginate though a whole XML result in SQL in a good way, with root tags and all?

Answer (score 0):

In SSMS 18 in order to have the `MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService` value persist I needed to edit that key's value in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Shell\Microsoft.XmlEditor.pkgdef` file.